# Center an object on screen after removing an iframe

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've got a centered `p` that I use to hold my embedded live stream object and an iframe for the chat like so

[image: Unhidden chat]

Now, I have a `JQuery` call that hides the chat, 
`<a id="hidechat" onClick="$('#chat_embed').hide();" href="#">[Hide Chat]</a>`

But that ends up with the stream box pulled way off to the left
[image: Hidden chat]

I'd love to have the chat re-align itself in the center of the screen without the ugly box on the right. I've tried setting a `float:left;` but the text below it wraps around and generally breaks the entire layout.

Is this possible with my current layout?

CSS:

```
    p
    {
        margin-left:auto;
        margin-right:auto;
        margin-bottom:1%;
        background-color:#121212;
        max-width:53%;
        max-height:75%;
        padding-top:25px;
        padding-left:25px;
        padding-right:25px;
        padding-bottom:25px;
    }
    p.streamblock
    {
        padding-top:25px;
        padding-left:25px;
        padding-right:25px;
        padding-bottom:25px;
        max-width:1000px;
    }
```

Embed code:

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" height="378" width="620" id="live_embed_player_flash" data="http://www.twitch.tv/widgets/live_embed_player.swf?channel=mychannel" bgcolor="#000000">
    <param name="movie" value="http://www.twitch.tv/widgets/live_embed_player.swf" />
    <param name="flashvars" value="hostname=www.twitch.tv&channel=mychannel&auto_play=true&start_volume=25" />
</object>
<iframe frameborder="0" scrolling="no" id="chat_embed" src="http://twitch.tv/chat/embed?channel=tronasaurusx&amp;popout_chat=true" height="378" width="350"></iframe>
```

Comment: Both the `object` and `iframe` tags have fixed dimensions. CSS may help. Any chance of seeing your code in action?

Comment: Sure, you can check it out at [tronasaurus.com](http://www.tronasaurus.com/)

Comment: Simply add `text-align: center` to `p.streamblock`. Also, consider changing your show/hide links' href to `javascript:void(0);`. Details here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/134845/href-tag-for-javascript-links-or-javascriptvoid0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**New HTML Markup** ->

```
<div class="streamblock">
  <!-- Twitch.tv embed code -->
<a href="#" onclick="$('#chat_embed').show();$('#showchat').hide();$('#hidechat').show();" id="showchat" style="display: inline;">[Show Chat]</a>
    <a href="#" onclick="$('#chat_embed').hide();$('#hidechat').hide();$('#showchat').show();" id="hidechat" style="display: none;">[Hide Chat]</a><br>
    <p class="objContainer">
  <object width="620" height="378" style="margin: 0px auto;" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" id="live_embed_player_flash" data="http://www.twitch.tv/widgets/live_embed_player.swf?channel=tronasaurusx" bgcolor="#000000">
    <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true">
    <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always">
    <param name="allowNetworking" value="all">
    <param name="movie" value="http://www.twitch.tv/widgets/live_embed_player.swf">
        <param name="flashvars" value="hostname=www.twitch.tv&amp;channel=tronasaurusx&amp;auto_play=true&amp;start_volume=25">
      </object>
     <!-- End Twitch.tv embed code -->
 <!-- Twitch.tv chat code -->
 <iframe width="350" scrolling="no" height="378" frameborder="0" style="display: none;" id="chat_embed" src="http://twitch.tv/chat/embed?channel=tronasaurusx&amp;popout_chat=true"></iframe>
 <br>
 <!-- End Twitch.tv chat code -->
  </p>
</div>
```

**New CSS markup** ->

```
div.streamblock{
  margin: 0px auto; 
  text-align: center; 
  max-width:1100px;
}
p{
  background-color: #121212;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-family: "Palatino Linotype",Tahoma,Serif;
  margin-bottom: 1%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  max-height: 75%;
  padding: 25px;
  text-indent: 10px;
}
```

I used the console to edit your HTML and make these changes on the fly. The above (when used exactly as I've given) will produce the desired result.

Comment: Worked great, thank you. What was the crucial mistake I was making?

Comment: needed a container to align the content within; using P's you can't align an `object`

Answer (score 0):

Hey now you can do this as like this

```
.streamblock > a{
float:right; 
margin-right:xx; // required to your design 
}
```